# bind value of callack to property of instance nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I want to permanently store a result of a callback function, here is the code:

```
class constants {
    constructor(){
       this.acquire()
    }

    acquire() {
       this.last_refresh = new Date().getDate();
        require('./db_slave').then(conn => {
            return conn.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='gen'").then(result => {
                this.tables = result
                console.log(result)
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            // handle error here
        });
    }

    tables() {
        this.refresh()
        return this.tables
    }
    refresh() { if (new Date().getDate() != this.last_refresh) this.acquire() }
}

module.exports = constants
```

but this is obviously not working because `this.tables = result` doesnt do anything...

Here is the file that is being called by this promise:

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var db = require('./db')

module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    host: db.host,
    user: db.user,
    password: db.password
}).then(conn => {
    console.log("connected to the DB");
    return conn;
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("error connecting to the DB", err);
    throw err;
});
```

How do i permanently store the result in that callback?

here is how i used these:

```
var db_constants = require('./database_service/db_constants')

let cons = new db_constants()

console.log(cons.tables())
```

Comment: what makes you think `this.tables = result` isn't doing anything? it surely will set `this.tables` to the value of `results` once the query is executed

Comment: where do you instantiate an instance of `db_tables` (e.g. `const x = new db_tables;` and where do you execute `acquire` method on that instance? (e.g. `x.acquire()`)

Comment: check the edits for more info

Comment: `while (true) console.log(cons.tables())` but `tables` isn't a function, it's a result of a query ... and why would you constantly `console.log` it in a loop like that, where it will never change because your loop wont let anything else run ... and you still never execute the `acquire` method anyway

Comment: ahhh, now we're getting something close to "real" code

Comment: left out some of the code...

Comment: `this.tables = result` will mean `tables()` function will be overwritten and no longer be a function! you can't have a method and a property with the same name

Comment: how do i check if it works then after I change the names?

Comment: I'd be tempted to write constants like https://jsfiddle.net/e0ok2dmu/ (still not the best in my opinion, but tried to make as few changes to your code as possible)

Comment: if not like this, then how would you doit ? thanks @JaromandaX

Comment: I'd remove the redundant code

Comment: can i ask you a question on skype? @JaromandaX

Comment: erm let me think about th .... no - I don't skype :p note, that code won't work as you expect, because of asynchrony - let me put up an answer instead

Comment: im getting the entire promise in my this.result variable now.. i need only the rows of the query result, how do i get that?

Comment: in your code, replace the last line with `cons.then(tables => console.log(tables))` - there's no way to *get around* asynchrony